# Why increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size slow down selects?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a server with 32G, a database of 20G. I run MySQL with innodb_buffer_pool_size of 10G, in trying to improve the performance increasing the value to 20G just slows down the select-queries. Can anybody explain me why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to get the general idea why the queries are slow.
2. Try [`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html) to see how buffer pool is used and what your InnoDB engine is doing.
3. There may be a lot of other factors in play here. Increasing `buffer_pool_size` you may be getting out of physical RAM (in accord with other configuration options), and then it goes into virtual memory, which is on disk... and disk operations are always slow...